# How to conditionally exclude or add columns when calculating row total

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure with a parameter defined like below

```
    @CategoryNames  NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

The above parameter gets a comma separated string from the application, for example the value can be like this `@StaffCategoryIds=N'Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5'`

Then i have the sample below sql query

```
SET @sql = @sql + 'TypeId, 
        TypeName, 
        Condition,
        Region, 
        (Category1 + Category2 + Category3 + Category4 + Category5) AS Total INTO ##QueryResults
FROM Table1;'
```

When computing my Total column in the query above, how can i first check whether a category column (say Category2 or Category5) exists in my `@StaffCategoryIds` comma separated string before including it in the computation of my Total column?

Eg. if 'Category2' exists in `@StaffCategoryIds`, then i include it in computation of Total else i exclude it.

Comment: In no particular order: (1) check for each and use a `case` around each column (`case when ',' + @CategoryNames + ',' like '%,Category1%' then Category1 else 0 end + ...`), (B) similarly, but handling the parsing first and using flags (`Category1 * @IncludeCategory1 +`) in the query, (iii) summing the columns separately and combining the values, as needed, after the query (perhaps in the application code), (IV) dynamic SQL with a query built from the list, ... . It depends on the number of rows, how often you run the query, `group by` or other clauses, ... .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    DECLARE @CategoryNames  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5',
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @sql = 'SELECT TypeId, 
        TypeName, 
        Condition,
        Region, ('+ REPLACE(@CategoryNames,',','+')+')
        AS Total INTO ##QueryResults
FROM Table1;'

SELECT @SQL
```

It returns:

```
SELECT TypeId, 
    TypeName, 
    Condition,
    Region, (Category1+Category2+Category3+Category4+Category5)
    AS Total INTO ##QueryResults 
FROM Table1;
```

Then you can Execute that statement:

```
EXEC @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate column names again system table "sys.columns" and whatever rows are returned , concatenate them as shown above to tun your query

```
  SELECT  [name]
    FROM 
        sys.syscolumns 
    WHERE [name] IN ('Col1,Col2...ColN')
    AND OBJECT_NAME(id) = 'TableName'
```